# How to save a Custom ArrayList to SQLite database and retrieve the values

Tags: java, android

So I have a customer Arraylist of type RedditPost:

This is a RedditPost Class:

I watched a tutorial for this Helper however I know a lot of it is not right and looking to save and retrieve my RedditPost ArrayList. If you would like to see more code please ask. Sorry I am really new to java

Comment: I really suggest you to checkout Room library. You can minimize much of the code. Also very easy to implement features and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use statements to insert bulk data in an optimized way, can use it like -

```
private static final String INSERT = "insert into "
            + TABLE_NAME+ " (" + COLUMN_1 + ", "
            + COLUMN_2 + ", "+COLUMN_3+") values (?, ?, ?)";

public void insertReditPosts(ArrayList<RedditPost> redditPosts) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        int aSize = redditPosts.size();
        database.beginTransaction();
        try {
            SQLiteStatement insert = database.compileStatement(INSERT);
            for (int i = 0; i < aSize; i++) {
                insert.bindString(1, redditPosts.get(i).id);
                insert.bindString(2, redditPosts.get(i).title);
                insert.bindString(3, redditPosts.get(i).url);
                insert.executeInsert();
            }
            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            database.endTransaction();
        }
    }
```

From your activity just call this method and pass the ArrayList it will store it into the database. Add this code to store clicked item on long press in list view

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int pos, long id) {
                Log.v("long clicked","pos: " + pos);
                RedditPost redditPost = postsArrayList.get(pos);
                if(redditPost!=null) {
                    addPostData(redditPost);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do I replae my whole SQL helper from this?

Comment: No just add it as a method to SqliteHelper class, and create an instance of a helper class and then call this method and pass list as a parameter @Bats

Comment: Could I add you on Discord or Skype to explain this?

Comment: Do check this article also for your understanding on how to insert in DB and retrieve it -http://mrbool.com/how-to-insert-data-into-a-sqlite-database-in-android/28895

Answer (score 0):

In your getData method:

```
    public List<RedditPost> getData(){

    List<RedditPost> posts = new ArrayList<>(); 

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
            Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            if(data.moveToFirst()){
          do{
    RedditPost post = new RedditPost();
    post.setId = data.getString(0);
    post.setTitle = data.getString(1);
    post.setUrl = data.getString(2);

    posts.add(post);
    }

    while(data.moveToNext);
    }

data.close;
    return posts;

        }
```

Comment: How would i use this method and also how would I recall the database?